# How to access a specific element with in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, object, element, treemap

I have used a Tree map to add data into my system.
I would like the user to be able to change certain value within the objects that have been added to the system.
In order for the user to choose the value that he/she wants to change I have printed it out to the screen using this.

```
for(Employee employee : employeeMap.values())
{
    System.out.println("Employe no :" +x+": "+employee);
    x++;
}
```

Then in order to access the objects element in the tree map that the user has chosen I have tried using this:

```
 System.out.println("this employee @@@@@##### is no: "+employeeMap.get(x));
```

Which is what I have successfully used with arraylists, But it does not seem to work it seems that all the value are null when using this approach.

Could some one please show me a better way of doing it.

Comment: have you put data into employeeMap before accessing its value?

Comment: yes I have like this 
   theEmployee = new Employee(randomIDno,fName, sName, gender, dPayLevel);
    employeeMap.put(randomIDno,theEmployee);

Comment: @Binyomin: you have to pass the key to get the value. i don't think that x is a key but a index for someother purpose

Comment: is randomIDno is the variable with randomly generated values ?

Comment: randomIDno is the key being used
how would I code it that it used the key to access the objects elements??  Thanks

Comment: RandomIDno was actually created via a random number but I am retaining this value for use later on in my code to use as a key. Saves time haha

Answer (score 2):

When accessing entries in a Map, you must use the key, not the index as in ArrayLists. If that key does not exist, you will get back null, which is what you are seeing. In the case of your example, you already have access to the `employee` object in your `for` loop, so you don't need to `get` it again from the map.

You might want to look at using `employeeMap.entrySet()` instead to iterate over both the key and value at once, and then you can say something like `employeeEntry.getKey()` to see what the key is for a given entry, like this (leaving out the generics because I don't know your key's type, and also assuming the key is the employee number):

```
for(Map.EntrySet employeeEntry : employeeMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Employee no :" + employeeEntry.getKey() +": " + employeeEntry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you access your map values by key

In your snippet, employeeMap.get(x), 'x' doesnt look like the key. Show us how you populate employeeMap

**Updated**

Since you are using the employee id as a key you can use it to retrieve the value

```
for (Employee employee : employeeMap.values()) {
    System.out.println("Employe no :" +employee.getRandomIDno()+": "+employee);
    Object thekey = employee.getRandomIDno();
}
```

and later,

```
System.out.println("this employee @@@@@##### is no: "+employeeMap.get(thekey));
```

Comment: Like this 
 theEmployee = new Employee(randomIDno,fName, sName, gender, dPayLevel);
    employeeMap.put(randomIDno,theEmployee);

Answer (score 0):

Map is key value pair.you just cannot access values from map using any index(like you are using x and incrementing it in a loop x++.) you need to use that key u entered while insertying data. i would suggest you the following way.

```
for(String key:employeeMap.keySet())
{
    System.out.println("Employe no :" +x+": "+employee.get(key));
    x++;
}
```

Comment: i like your idea but when I enter it into my system I get the error
"Cannot find symbol method get int"
I changed the value of the Key from string to int as my keys are being entered as int values